# Datetime and selectbox

Tags: jquery, angularjs, momentjs, timepicker

I am using [angular-jquery-timepicker directive](https://github.com/Recras/angular-jquery-timepicker) to fill a selectbox with hours in AM/PM format.

I get this hours from a JSON like this:

```
[
   {
      id: "34", day_of_week: "2", start_time: "8:00 AM",
      end_time: "12:00 PM", duration: 30
   },
   …
]
```

Here, initialize the directive options according the docs:

```
for(var i = 0; i < httpData.data.length; i++)
{
httpData.data[i].start_time = moment(httpData.data[i].start_time, 'g:i A');
httpData.data[i].end_time = moment(httpData.data[i].end_time, 'g:i A');
httpData.data[i].options = {
   step: httpData.data[i].duration,
   timeFormat: 'g:i A',
   asMoment: true
};
}
$scope.settings = httpData.data;
```

And inside into a ng-repeat:

```
<input class="custom-input" ui-timepicker="setting.options" type="text" name="start" ng-model="setting.start_time" required />

<input class="custom-input" ui-timepicker="setting.options" type="text" name="end" ng-model="setting.end_time" required />
```

The problem is that the generated start_time and end_time in the loop have 00:00 hs, so 12:00 AM is selected in the selectbox.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hmm did you try using moment(httpData.data[i].start_time, 'hh:mm A'); instead?

Comment: I will add it as an answer. Please, consider marking it as the correct one if it really helped you. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using:

```
moment(httpData.data[i].start_time, 'hh:mm A');
```

Instead of

```
moment(httpData.data[i].start_time, 'g:i A');
```

You can find the complete list of tokens [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/)